# Creating a mini filesystem in Java

Tags: java, object, tree, hashmap, filesystems

I have an assignment to create a mini filesystem that supports a limited number of filesystem operations and to add functions to it as I go along.

The task I'm currently on is to implement the operation `ln`wich is basicly creating a link to an excisting directory or file (think of it as creating a shortcut for a folder or file and putting it in another folder).

My thought was to add an `ArrayList`to my INode class that works like a pointer, however I can't seem to figure out how to access them. I realised that it's probably the way I'm adding my new objects, ah thought that I got was to create another `ArrayList<INode> pointer` that would basicly work like `pointer.add(new INodeDirectory(paths[i]);` but not sure if that will work or if it's the best way to go about this, so thought I would aks for some pointers and how you would go about doing it.

Some relevant code:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdOut;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MiniFs implements FileSystem {

  private final INodeDirectory root;
  private HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  private int n = 0; //Number of objects created

  public MiniFs() {
    root = new INodeDirectory("/");
    map.put("/",n);
  }
  //Create a directory/folder
  @Override
  public void mkdir(String path) {
    String paths[] = path.split("/");
    if(paths.length == 2){
        INodeDirectory node = new INodeDirectory(paths[1]);
        n++;
        map.put(paths[1],n);
        StdOut.println("OK.");
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 1; i < paths.length; i++){
            if(i == paths.length - 1){
                if(map.containsKey(paths[i])){
                    StdOut.println("Directory already excists");
                }
                else{
                    INodeDirectory node = new INodeDirectory(paths[i]);
                    n++;
                    map.put(paths[i],n);
                    StdOut.println("OK.");
                }
            }
            else if(map.containsKey(paths[i]) == false){
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Error: you have to create " + paths[i] + " first!");
            }
        }
    }
  }
  //Create a file
  @Override
  public void touch(String path) {
    String paths[] = path.split("/");
    if(paths.length == 2){
        INodeFile node = new INodeFile(paths[paths.length - 1]);
        n++;
        map.put(paths[paths.length - 1], n);
        StdOut.println("OK.");
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 1; i < paths.length; i++){
            if(i == paths.length - 1){
                if(map.containsKey(paths[i])){
                    StdOut.println("File already excists");
                } 
                else{
                    INodeFile node = new INodeFile(paths[i]);
                    n++;
                    map.put(paths[i],n);
                    StdOut.println("OK.");
                }
            }
            else if(map.containsKey(paths[i]) == false){
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You have to create " + paths[i] + " first!");
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

INode class:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

public abstract class INode {

  private String name;

  private long accessTime;

  public INode(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.accessTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public long getAccessTime() {
    return accessTime;
  }

  public void setAccessTime(long accessTime) {
    this.accessTime = accessTime;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

INodeDirectory class:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

public class INodeDirectory extends INode {

  public INodeDirectory(String name) {
    super(name);
  }
}
```

INodeFile class:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

public class INodeFile extends INode {

  public INodeFile(String name) {
    super(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to ask a concise question, at least if you expect a concise answer. As it is currently, your question does not fit well with SO.

Comment: @Durandal yeah I got a bit carried away, edited my question now. Hope it got better.

Answer (score 0):

Its still hard to get what you're asking...

Anyway, keep the data where it logically belongs. A FileSystem maps logically perfectly to the Composite pattern (thats a node tree). All a Node needs to really know is who is its parent (the directory that contains it), and depending on if it model a File or Directory, its actualy binary content, or its child nodes. These are mutually exclusive, so it makes sense to model them as different classes with a common ancestor (like you already did).

The responsibility of child node management can be logically placed on the parent node, which can by definition only be a directory node. So the directory node class *has* a collection of its direct child nodes. Logically no global map of names exists, the entire file system is accessed simply by knowing its root node; *everything* can be resolved by navigating into the tree starting from the root node.

The concept of a "current directory" can be realized by simply holding a reference to said directory node. Operations working with relative pathes simply treat the current directory node as the root.

At some point you will need to distinguish between File and Directory, e.g. only a Directory will manage children. There are multiple ways to model heterogenous API capabilities (again take a look at the Composite pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) for nodes and leafs.